# Event listener watching for browser docked to top of screen

Tags: dom-events

I have a case where I use an event listener to resize a div :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
                            
  var responsiveWidth = document.querySelector(".responsive").offsetWidth;
  var resumeWidth = node.offsetWidth;
                            
  if(responsiveWidth<resumeWidth){                              
    node.style.scale = responsiveWidth/resumeWidth;
    targetNode.style.height = `${node.offsetHeight*responsiveWidth/resumeWidth}px`;                             
   }
});
```

Though I have a problem when user grab the browser top handle, undocks the browser and dock it back up. The resize event doesn't trigger in this case and my resized DIV stays in an undesired size.

I have been trying to use `fullscreenchange` listener as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event with no luck

Would there be an event that triggers when the browser is docked/undocked from edge of screen ?